# How to access backbone model from custom javascript outside of view

Tags: 8, commerce, javascript, ajax

I was wondering if there is a way to access backbone model variable outside the scope of the backbone model/view.This is the backbone model:

```
function (Backbone, Drupal) {
  Drupal.addToCart.AddToCartModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
      defaultVariation: '',
      selectedVariation: '',
      attributes: {},
      renderedAttributes: {},
      injectedFields: {},
      variations: {},
      variationCount: 0,
      quantity: 1,
      unit_box: 1,
      type: 'commerce_product_variation_attributes'
    },
    initialize: function initialize() {
      this.set('variationCount', Object.keys(this.get('variations')).length);
      this.set('selectedVariation', this.getVariation(this.get('defaultVariation')));
    },
    // ... some getter and setter
  });
})(Backbone, Drupal);
```

And this is the view:

```
(function ($, Backbone, _, Drupal) {
  Drupal.addToCart.AddToCartView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function initialize() {
      var _this = this;

      var defaultVariation = this.model.getVariation(this.model.getDefaultVariation());
      _.each(this.model.getAttributes(), function (attribute, i) {
        var attributeFieldName = 'attribute_' + attribute.id;
        if (defaultVariation.hasOwnProperty(attributeFieldName)) {
          _this.selectedAttributes[attributeFieldName] = defaultVariation[attributeFieldName];
        }
      });
      this.render();
    },

    events: {
      'click .form-submit': 'addToCart',
      'change .attribute-widgets input[type="radio"]': 'onAttributeChange',
      'change .attribute-widgets select': 'onAttributeChange',
      'change .variations-select select': 'onVariationTitleChange',
    },
    // ... events on...
    onAttributeChange: function onAttributeChange(event) {
      Drupal.detachBehaviors();
      this.selectedAttributes[event.target.name] = event.target.value;
      var selectedVariation = this.model.getResolvedVariation(this.selectedAttributes);
      this.model.setSelectedVariation(selectedVariation.uuid);
      var injectedFields = this.model.getInjectedFieldsForVariation(selectedVariation.uuid);
      Object.values(injectedFields).map(function (injectedField) {
        $('.' + injectedField.class).html(injectedField.output);
      });
      Drupal.attachBehaviors();
      
      $('.banner.wishlist').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
          url: Drupal.url('wishlistupdate'),

          method: 'POST',
          data: JSON.stringify([{
              'variation': $(this).attr('data-variation')
            }]),
          contentType: 'application/json;',
          dataType: 'json'
        }).done(function (data) {
          // <--- HERE IS WHERE I WANT TO ACCESS BACKBONE MODEL TO ALTER SOME PROPERTIES
      }); 
     });
    },
// ... some other events subscribers
});
  Drupal.addToCart.AddToCartView.prototype.selectedAttributes = {};
})(jQuery, Backbone, _, Drupal);
```

And this is the theme settings:

```
(function ($, _, Drupal, drupalSettings) {
  Drupal.theme.addToCartButton = function () {
    return drupalSettings.theme.commerce_cart_flyout_add_to_cart_button;
  };
  //... some other themes functions
  Drupal.theme.addToCartVariationSelect = function (_) {
    return function (args) {
      var template = _.template(drupalSettings.theme.commerce_cart_flyout_add_to_cart_variation_select);
      return template(args);
    };
  }(_);

  Drupal.addToCart = {};
  Drupal.behaviors.addToCart = {
    attach: function attach(context) {
      $(context).find('[data-product]').once('flyout-add-to-cart').each(function (k, el) {
        var model = new Drupal.addToCart.AddToCartModel(drupalSettings.addToCart[el.dataset.product]);
        new Drupal.addToCart.AddToCartView({ el: el, model: model });
      });
    }
  };
})(jQuery, _, Drupal, drupalSettings);
```

What I want is to access backbone model variables on ajax done method, but I didn't find a way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

After some debugging I have found I can access drupalSettings object and It has a property addToCart with all the data I need.